# JMS Serializer: how to use camel case for properties

Tags: symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using FOS Rest bundle and JMS Serializer to create a REST Api. The problem is I would like to keep the property names in the JSON response camel cased instead of using _.

For example, I have a property called employeeIdentifier, by default that gets converted to employee_identifier.

I saw that there's an option in the config to disable the lowercase and get rid of the _, but then it becomes EmployeeIdentifier.

Is there any way that JMS Serializer keeps the original name of the property? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 42):

I found a way to do it globally, if you want to keep the property names as is you need to use the `IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy`

There are several ways to accomplish this, first by changing the config(Thanks @Phantom):

```
#config.yml
jms_serializer:
    property_naming: 
        id: 'jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy'
```

Second, you could override the default alias for this

```
services:
    jms_serializer.naming_strategy:
        alias: jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy
```

The bundle defines these https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.xml so you should be able to override them

Another way to do it is when you initialize the builder:

```
$serializebuilder = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create();
$serializebuilder->setPropertyNamingStrategy(new \JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy());
$serializer = $serializebuilder->build();
```

Comment: no, that doesnt make any difference just removes the separador, so employeeIdentifier gets employeeidentifier

Comment: @petekaner did a little more digging found what you are looking for

Comment: seems like it should work, but I get this error   You have requested a non-existent parameter "jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy.class".

Comment: @petekaner I updated the answer with a different method.

Comment: Thanks this helped me

Comment: You may also change strategy not by overriding a service alias, but instead changing your config, e.g. in `config.yml`

`jms_serializer: property_naming: id: 'jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy'`

Comment: added to `config > packages > jms_serializer.yaml` in SF4; does not seem to work

Comment: While this works, it doesn't allow the serialized names from being overridden.   For instance, `<property name="idPublic" serialized-name="id" expose="true"/>` outputs `idPublic` and not `id`.

Comment: This helped me, using JMSSerializer 2.4

Comment: Worked for me with this config in `config/packages/jms_serializer.yaml` :
jms_serializer:
    property_naming:
        id: jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy
and removing the cache manually
https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/1037

Answer (score 5):

Having upgraded jms/serilizer-bundle from 1.1 to 2.2 the parameter hack described above did not work. You can override the service definition as follows:

```
#app/config/services.yml
services:
    ....
    jms_serializer.serialized_name_annotation_strategy:
        class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\SerializedNameAnnotationStrategy
        arguments:
            - '@jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy'
```

Comment: Works on Symfony 5.2 & jms/serializer-bundle: ^3.3

Comment: Works on "jms/serializer-bundle": "^4.0" and symfony 5.4

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me (Symfony 4.4 and JMS ^3.8) with this config in `config/packages/jms_serializer.yaml` :

```
jms_serializer:
    property_naming:
        id: jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy
```

and removing the cache manually

https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/1037

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it but it's not the best way I think, there's an annotation SerializedName wich allows you to override the property serialization. The problem is that you have to do it one by one on every property with camel case, here's the documentation:
YAML: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference
Annotation: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#serializedname

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the following to parameters.yml instead of config.yml:

`jms_serializer.serialized_name_annotation_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\SerializedNameAnnotationStrategy`