# JMS Serializer: overriding default naming strategy in symfony 4 has no effect

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529287/jms-serializer-how-to-use-camel-case-for-properties) proposing a neat way of overriding globally the default naming strategy in config.yml

but this is for symfony 3 and I am on symfony 4 so I added the line to my `config > packages > jms_serializer.yaml` but this has no effect at all.

```
jms_serializer:
  visitors:
    xml_serialization:
        format_output: '%kernel.debug%'
  property_naming:
    id: 'jms_serializer.identical_property_naming_strategy'
```

Does anyone understand why ?

I do dependency injection of `SerializerInterface $serializer` to use the serializer as it is not possible to call the service from `AbstractController` in SF4. `Controller` is deprecated in SF4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing `var/cache` manually. When I cleared cache with `cache:clear` command it didn't work, but after I cleaned it manually it did!

I hope this solution will help you too.

Answer (score -1):

Add `jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy` to your parameters configuration.