# Override JMS Serializer global camelCase

Tags: php, jms-serializer

I wish to default to outputting camel case names, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43529530/1032531) provides an excellent solution.

```
$serializer= \JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()
    ->setDebug(true)
    ->addMetadataDir(APP_ROOT.'/config/serializer')
    ->setPropertyNamingStrategy(new \JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy())
    ->build();
```

I also wish to occasionally override the serialized name, however, when doing it the traditional way using `serialized-name`, the serializer does not follow the instructions, and outputs `idPublic` instead of the desired `id`.  If I remove the global override to using identical property names, `id` is outputted as desired, however, obviously all the other properties are snake-case (i.e. `other_property`) and need to be individually configured which is not desirable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<serializer>
    <class name="Fully\Qualfied\ClassName" exclusion-policy="ALL">
        <property name="idPublic" serialized-name="id" expose="true"/>
        <property name="name" expose="true"/>
        <property name="otherProperty" expose="true"/>
    </class>
</serializer>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping https://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Fully\Qualfied\ClassName" table="systems">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="idPublic" type="integer" column="id_public"/>
    <field name="name" type="string"/>
    <field name="otherProperty" type="string" length="45" column="other_property"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

As an alternate approach, I even tried to eliminating the normal property and using a virtual property instead, but it too resulted in the name `idPublic`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<serializer>
    <class name="Fully\Qualfied\ClassName" exclusion-policy="ALL">
        <virtual-property method="getIdPublic" serialized-name="id" expose="true"/>
        <property name="name" expose="true"/>
        <property name="otherProperty" expose="true"/>
    </class>
</serializer>
```

How can one override JMS Serializer's global configuration to use identical names?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is the "right" way to do this, but it works.

```
class SerializerNamingStrategy implements \JMS\Serializer\Naming\PropertyNamingStrategyInterface
{
    public function translateName(\JMS\Serializer\Metadata\PropertyMetadata $property)
    {
        return $property->serializedName??$property->name;
    }
}
```